# Get Uri from MainViewModel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make an aplication where I have a lot of link to differen web sites on a stackpanel, getting there content from a `MainViewMode`l, so when I click on the description it opens the web via `WebBrowserTask`. However, I want to have the Uri on the `MainViewModel` and get that info in the .cs, which takes me to the site

My xaml code is

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17" Tap=Open_Web>
<Image Height="100" Width="100"   Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="{Binding ImgWeb}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <StackPanel Width="311">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                         </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
            </ListBox>
```

My .cs is

```
private void Open_Web(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
        webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("I DONT KNOW");
        webBrowserTask.Show();
```

And my MainViewModel code is:

```
this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "Web Name", LineTwo = "Web description", Uri = "http://WebSite.com" });
```

If I dont bind the info, It works, but I dont know how to get the Uri on `webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("I DONT KNOW");` form the MainViewModel

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the beginning of Open_Web method

```
var templateRoot = (FrameworkElement)sender;
var dataItem = (ItemViewModel)templateRoot.DataContext;
var uri = dataItem.Uri;
```